# How to stop the circular progress at certain level?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a code snippet from a website for a circular progress bar, but now I am stuck. I can't solve how to stop progress bar at particular point (let's say 73% or 90%). How can I achieve that?

```js
const numb = document.querySelector(".numb");
let counter = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  if (counter == 100) {
    clearInterval();
  } else {
    counter += 1;
    numb.textContent = counter + "%";
  }
}, 80);
```

```css
.circular {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}

.circular .inner,
.circular .outer,
.circular .circle {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.circular .inner {
  top: 36%;
  left: 37%;
  height: 117px;
  width: 117px;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.circular .circle {
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.circular .numb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #4158d0;
}

.circular .bar {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F2F5F5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 150px, 150px, 75px);
}

.circle .bar .progress {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 75px, 150px, 0px);
}

.circle .bar .progress,
.dot span {
  background: #4158d0;
}

.circle .left .progress {
  z-index: 1;
  animation: left 4s linear both;
}

@keyframes left {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.circle .right {
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.circle .right .progress {
  animation: right 4s linear both;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes right {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

.circle .dot {
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  animation: dot 8s linear both;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}

.circle .dot span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

@keyframes dot {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circular">
  <div class="inner"></div>
  <div class="outer"></div>
  <div class="numb">
    0%
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <div class="dot">
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="bar left">
      <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar right">
      <div class="progress"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could say if(counter == 73) { animation.pause()  }

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numb = document.querySelector(".numb");
            let counter = 0;
            setInterval(()=>{
              if(counter == 73){
                clearInterval();
              }else{
                counter+=1;
                numb.textContent = counter + "%";
              }
            }, 80);
```

```css
.circular{
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.circular .inner, .circular .outer, .circular .circle{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 6;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.circular .inner{
  top: 36%;
  left: 37%;
  height: 117px;
  width: 117px;
  margin: -40px 0 0 -40px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.circular .circle{
  z-index: 1;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.circular .numb{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #4158d0;
}
.circular .bar{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #F2F5F5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 150px, 150px, 75px);
}
.circle .bar .progress{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
  clip: rect(0px, 75px, 150px, 0px);
}
.circle .bar .progress, .dot span{
  background: #4158d0;
}
.circle .left .progress{
  z-index: 1;
  animation: left 4s linear both;
}
@keyframes left {
  100%{
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
.circle .right{
  z-index: 3;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.circle .right .progress{
  animation: right 4s linear both;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
@keyframes right {
  100%{
    transform: rotate(80deg);
  }
}
.circle .dot{
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
  animation: dot 8s linear both;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
.circle .dot span {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  
}
@keyframes dot{
  0% {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    z-index: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
        <div class="circular">
            <div class="inner"></div>
            <div class="outer"></div>
            <div class="numb">
               0%
            </div>
            <div class="circle">
               <div class="bar left">
                  <div class="progress"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="bar right">
                  <div class="progress"></div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```